# BeautifulSoup.find_all() does not print all results

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am working on a web scraping project in which I want to scrape all the elements inside a particular table. this is the [website](https://www.alkemlabs.com/rx-products.php) I want to scrape the data from.

Here is my code so far

```
url = 'https://www.alkemlabs.com/rx-products.php'
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    ths = tr.find_all('th')
    try:
        print(f'Brand: {ths[0].text}, Therapy Area - : {tds[0].text}, SKU - : {tds[1].text}, Strength: {tds[2].text}')
    except: continue
```

The output for the code is as follows

```
Brand: XONE SB, Therapy Area - : Anti-infective, SKU - : XONE SB 250MG INJECTION (VIALS), Strength: CEFTRIAXONE 250MG + SULBACTAM 125MG
Brand: XONE SB, Therapy Area - : Anti-infective, SKU - : XONE SB 500 MG INJECTION (VIALS), Strength: CEFTRIAXONE 500MG + SULBACTAM 250MG
Brand: Acuflam, Therapy Area - : PAIN & ANTI-INFLAMMMATORY, SKU - : ACUFLAM MR TABLETS (10'S), Strength: Acelofenac 100 mg + Paracetamol 325 mg + Chlorzoxazone 250 mg
```

The code only prints out three rows from three tables whereas there are many more rows in the tables.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    target = soup.findAll("th", scope="row")
    for tar in target:
        print("Brand: {:<15}, Therapy Area - : {:<50}, SKU - : {:<30}, Strength: {}".format(
            tar.text, *[item.text for item in tar.find_all_next("td")[:3]]))


main("https://www.alkemlabs.com/rx-products.php")
```

Output Sample:

```
Brand: A TO Z         , Therapy Area - : Vitamins / Minerals / Nutrients                   , SKU - : NEW A TO Z GOLD CAPSULES (15'S), Strength: ASCORBIC ACID + BENFOTIAMINE + BETACAROTENE + DOCONEXENT + FOLIC ACID + ICOSAPENT + PROCYANIDIN + PYRIDOXINE + THIOCTIC ACID + VITAMIN E
Brand: XONE SB        , Therapy Area - : Anti-infective                                    , SKU - : XONE SB 250MG INJECTION (VIALS), Strength: CEFTRIAXONE 250MG + SULBACTAM 125MG
Brand: XONE SB        , Therapy Area - : Anti-infective                                    , SKU - : XONE SB 500 MG INJECTION (VIALS), Strength: CEFTRIAXONE 500MG + SULBACTAM 250MG
Brand: XONE SB        , Therapy Area - : Anti-infective                                    , SKU - : XONE SB 1GM INJECTION (VIALS) , Strength: CEFTRIAXONE 1000MG + SULBACTAM 500MG
Brand: COLPEP         , Therapy Area - : Gastro Intestinal                                 , SKU - : COLPEP SUSPENSION (30ML)      , Strength: DICYCLOMINE HCl 10MG + ACTIVATED DIMETHICONE 40MG / 5ML SUSP
Brand: COLPEP         , Therapy Area - : Gastro Intestinal                                 , SKU - : COLPEP DROPS (15ML)           , Strength: ACTIVATED DIMETHICONE 40MG + DILL OIL 0.005ML + FENNEL OIL 0.0007MG / ML SYRUP
Brand: COLPEP         , Therapy Area - : Gastro Intestinal                                 , SKU - : COLPEP SPAS TABLETS (10'S)    , Strength: Aceclofenac 100mg + Drotravarine 80mg Tablets
Brand: DIGIPEN        , Therapy Area - : Gastro Intestinal                                 , SKU - : DIGIPEN JUNIOR SYRUP (60ML)   , Strength: Alpha Amylase I.P. 100Mg (Bacterial 1:800) + Papain I.P. 50 Mg
Brand: DIGIPEN        , Therapy Area - : Gastro Intestinal                                 , SKU - : DIGIPEN DROPS (15ML)          , Strength: Alpha Amylase I.P. 20mg (Bacterial 1:800) + Papain I.P. 10mg + Dill oil B.P. 2mg + Anise oil B.P. 2mg + Caraway oil B.P. 2mg
Brand: DIGIPEN        , Therapy Area - : Gastro Intestinal                                 , SKU - : DIGIPEN TABLETS (10'S)        , Strength: Protease 3600 HUT + Amylase 1200 SKB + Hemicellulase 600 XU +á Lipase 450 FIP + Lactalase 250 ALU + Alpha Galactosidase 50 Gal U Chewable Tablets
Brand: HEMFER         , Therapy Area - : Gynaec.                                           , SKU - : HEMFER CAPSULES (NEW)(30'S)   , Strength: FERROUS GLYCINE SULPHATE 50MG (EQUI. IRON) + FOLIC ACID 0.5MG + CYANOCOBALAMINE 7.5MCG + ZINC SULPHATE 5MG (EQUI. ZINC)
Brand: HEMFER         , Therapy Area - : Gynaec.                                           , SKU - : HEMFER INJECTION (5ML)        , Strength: FERRIC HYDROXIDE WITH SUCROSE 100MG (EQUI. IRON)
Brand: HEMFER         , Therapy Area - : Gynaec.                                           , SKU - : HEMFER KID SYRUP (60ML)       , Strength: FERROUS GLYCINE SULPHATE 25MG (IRON EQUI.) + FOLIC ACID 0.25MG + CYANOCOBALAMINE 3.75MCG + ZINC SULPHATE MONOHYDRATEá3.5MG (ZINC EQUI.) / 5 ML DROPS
Brand: HEMFER         , Therapy Area - : Gynaec.                                           , SKU - : HEMFER SYRUP (225ML)          , Strength: FERROUS GLYCINE SULPHATE 50MG (EQUI. IRON) + FOLIC ACID 0.5MG + CYANOCOBALAMINE 7.5MCG + ZINC SULPHATE 2.5MG (EQUI. ZINC) + D-BIOTIN 100MCG / 15ML
Brand: HEMFER         , Therapy Area - : Gynaec.                                           , SKU - : HEMFER DROPS (15ML)           , Strength: FERROUS GLYCINE SULPHATE 10MG (IRON EQUI.) + FOLIC ACID 100MCG + CYANOCOBALAMINE 1.5MCG / ML DROPS
Brand: PIPZO          , Therapy Area - : Anti-infective                                    , SKU - : PIPZO 4.5 GM INJECTION (VIAL) , Strength: PIPERACILLIN 4G + TAZOBACTAM 500MG INJ
Brand: PIPZO          , Therapy Area - : Anti-infective                                    , SKU - : PIPZO 4.5GM INJECTION (VIAL)  , Strength: PIPERACILLIN 4G + TAZOBACTAM 500MG INJ
Brand: PIPZO          , Therapy Area - : Anti-infective                                    , SKU - : PIPZO 4.5GM INJECTION (HOSPITAL SUPPLY), Strength: PIPERACILLIN 4G + TAZOBACTAM 500MG INJ
Brand: PIPZO          , Therapy Area - : Anti-infective                                    , SKU - : PIPZO-1.125 INJECTION (VIAL)  , Strength: PIPERACILLIN 1G + TAZOBACTAM 125MG INJ
Brand: PIPZO          , Therapy Area - : Anti-infective                                    , SKU - : PIPZO 1.125GM INJECTION (VIAL), Strength: PIPERACILLIN 1G + TAZOBACTAM 125MG INJ
Brand: PIPZO          , Therapy Area - : Anti-infective                                    , SKU - : PIPZO 2.25 GM INJECTION (VIAL), Strength: PIPERACILLIN 2G + TAZOBACTAM 250MG INJ
Brand: PIPZO          , Therapy Area - : Anti-infective                                    , SKU - : PIPZO 2.25GM INJECTION (VIAL) , Strength: PIPERACILLIN 2G + TAZOBACTAM 250MG INJ
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to break after all the elements from the first table is printed?

Comment: Then you can just Select the first table and parse it. Also you can use pandas.read_html and select first table ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is because the structure of HTML is not as you are expecting in the code. Due to this, many of the calls are going to catch block

print(tr) in for loop and you will get to know the structure of each row. Then you can modify your code according to the requirement